# Example of "sequence $μ_n$ is not weakly convergent, because $f$ is not a density"

Tags: probability

Can someone give me an example that the $f_n$converges point wise to some $f$, but the probability distribution sequence $μ_n$ is not weakly convergent, because $f$ is not a density? Assume that $f_n$ is Lebesgue density of $\mu_n$, and $f$ for $\mu$ respectively. 
[please correct me: I start with $f_n(x)= 1/n $ for $1<x<n$, $=0$ otherwise. In this case, $f_n$ converges to $0=f$, but $f$ is not a density. But I am confused on $u_n$.]

Comment: you already have it. $\mu_n(A)=\int_A f_n(x)dx$ for measurable $A\subset \mathbb{R}$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take $f_n(x)=1/n$ if $x\in [0,n]$ and $0$ otherwise (otherwise its integral over the real line is not $1$). The sequence $(f_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ indeed converges pointwise to $0$. Observe that the cumulative distribution function of $\mu$ is 
$$\mu_n\left(\left(-\infty,t\right]\right)=\begin{cases}0&\mbox{if }t\leqslant 0\\
t/n&\mbox{if }0<t<n\\
1&\mbox{if }n\leqslant t\end{cases},$$
hence for each $t$, $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\mu_n\left(\left(-\infty,t\right]\right)=0$, which proves that we cannot have the convergence in distribution.